# array repetindo resultados

Tags: php, array

Não estou entendendo porque meu array está repetindo os resultados, o meu laço para percorrer ele é assim:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($estados); $i++) {
   foreach ($estados[$i] as $key => $valor) {
      echo "<option value='".$estados[$i]['cod_estados']."'>".$estados[$i]['nome']."</option>";
   }
}
```

Esse laço está exibindo no select da seguinte forma:

```
ACRE
ACRE
ACRE
ACRE
ACRE
ACRE
ALAGOAS
ALAGOAS
ALAGOAS
ALAGOAS
ALAGOAS
ALAGOAS
```

etc...

Aqui vai um exemplo de como o array é:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [cod_estados] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [sigla] => AC
        [1] => AC
        [nome] => ACRE
        [2] => ACRE
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cod_estados] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [sigla] => AL
        [1] => AL
        [nome] => ALAGOAS
        [2] => ALAGOAS
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [cod_estados] => 3
        [0] => 3
        [sigla] => AP
        [1] => AP
        [nome] => AMAPÁ
        [2] => AMAPÁ
    )
```

Talvez seja um erro bobo, mas não estou conseguindo entender, vi que ele está repetindo uma vez para cada item do array interno.

Comment: pq usa um `for` e dentro dele um `foreach`? só o `foreach` deve resolver.

Comment: Não da certo, o array é multidimensional.

Comment: Mas está a utiliza-lo como se fosse unidimensional quando faz algo como `$estados[$i]['cod_estados']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um `for` a mais no seu código e no `foreach` é especificado `$estados[$i]` quando apenas um foreach resolveria. `$valor` é equivalmente `$estados[$i]` então na hora de montar as options basta chamar ele.

```
foreach ($estados as $valor) {
  echo "<option value='".$valor['cod_estados']."'>".$valor['nome']."</option>";
}
```